# Unable to add a table dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to add a row to an existing table dynamically on the click of a button. But the code doesn't seem to work. I have checked, the program execution does come inside this function but there is something wrong with the code that doesn't add the rows.

Any help is appreciated. Below is my code excerpt:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#addRow").click(function(){
        var scorePrev = Number($("#scoreNum").text());
        var score = scorePrev++;
        var markup = "<tr> <td>" + score + "</td>" + "<td><select><option value='pack'>"+ Pack + "</option> <option value>" + Char + "</option> <option>"  + Hex + "</option> </select></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> </tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });

});
```

Comment: are you sure the target like `$("table tbody")` exists ( `console.log($("table tbody"))` )? can you post the creation of your table?

Comment: I don't see `Pack` or `Char` or `Hex` defined as variables

Comment: Those are not variables. Just literals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not concatenate the texts between option tags. That's it and you are good to go! See the difference in the value of the 'markup' variable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#addRow").click(function(){
      var scorePrev = Number($("#scoreNum").text());
      var score = scorePrev++;
      var markup = "<tr> <td>" + score + "</td>" + "<td><select><option value='pack'>Pack</option> <option value>Char</option> <option>Hex</option> </select></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> <td><input type='text'></td> </tr>";
      $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Don't just drop a block of code in and expect everyone to know what you did.

Comment: Could you please provide working jsFiddle that will give us idea?

Comment: This answer *assumes* that the OP meant the values to be literals, and not variables they forgot to define.

Comment: Sorry for that. I already edited it and included the explanation.

Comment: Hey.. You are right. It worked like a charm!! Thanks for your answer.